# Binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k+1}{n+1\choose k}=1$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I need help solving this problem in my mind so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

The problem is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k+1}{n+1\choose k}=1$$

Can someone explain to me how this equals 1?

Thanks in advance !

Best regards!

Comment: Hint: Expand $(1+(-1))^{n+1}$ (which is obviously $0$) and compare it to the expression you have.

Answer (score 2):

By the Binomial theorem,
$$
0 = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{k + 1} \binom{n + 1}{k}
$$
Rearranging the first term gives you the desired equality.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that is usually fruitful when trying to prove stuff about sums of binomial coefficients is to use induction. In this case, simple induction on $n$, together with the property that $\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$ should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Another method
$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k y^{n-k}$$
Substitute $x = -1$ and $y = 1$ to observe
$$0 = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \stackrel{\text{multiply by (-1)}}{\implies} 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n}{k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that by the Binomial Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

$$[1+(-1)]^{n+1} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(1)^{n+1-k}(-1)^k$$

We observe that the first term of the expression on the left hand side is 1, therefore

$$0 = 1 + \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(1)^{n+1-k}(-1)^k$$

Since $1^{n+1-k} = 1, \forall k \in \{1,\cdots,n+1\}$

$$0 = 1 + \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^k$$

Move the second term to the left,

$$-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^k = 1$$

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k} = 1 $$

We obtain the desired result.